# Application logging in Glassfish3

Tags: logging, glassfish-3

I have migrated an application from Tomcat to Glassfish in order to take advantage of the Application server functionalities.

It all works fine except for logging. In debug mode, I can see the log entries in the server log but in normal operation there is nothing.

I have added a line (via the Glassfish Admin app) to both default-config and domain-config `logging.properties`. The line in question is `ch.sertal.level=FINE`

The way the loggers are defined is the same for every class:

```
private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
```

The package always starts with ch.sertal

I use maven for the dependency management and there is no Logging dependency in the pom.xml. I assume the libraries are provided as the project compiles OK.

Where should I check next?

Thank you for your help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, the row in logging.properties

```
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.level=INFO
```

was

```
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.level=OFF
```

so obviously it would not log anything.